# Can't get Params from id routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history

I'm stuck with a problem in my project. I'm trying to show a component and work with the this.props.match.params, but no matter what I do I get undefined.

Routes:

```
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Fragment>
            <Header/>
            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/show/:id" component={Show}/>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
                </Switch>
            </main>
        </Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

then I have a handler on my home route:

```
async handleSubmit(searchId) {
    const id = await DwellingService.findSiocId(searchId);
    if (id) {
        this.props.history.push(`/show/${id}`);
    }
}
```

and finally on my show component

```
   componentDidMount() {
            console.log(this.props.match.params)
            const {id} = this.props.match.params;
            if (id) {
                this.props.requestFindDwelling(id);
            }
        }
```

So I have been researching and I think is not a react router problem, first when I try to access the routes by typing them I was getting unexpected > on my bundle.js which was solved adding  `<base href="/" />` on the index.html.
Now my component is rendering ok by the console.log of the show component is giving me this:

```
isExact:false
params:{}
path:"/show"
url:"/show"
```

When I started the project to be able to use browserhistory and not getting error by refreshing the page I had to add this to my index file:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

For the kind of error I get I'm supposing the route is not being found and is redirecting me to /show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/show/:id" component={Show}/>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

This will never render `Home` as `Switch` renders first thing that matches and `/` will match always the first route. Not sure if this will fix the problem but try and let me know:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/> // exact is important
    <Route path="/show/:id" component={Show}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: this solved it, it was a matter of order, i was hours trying to fix it haha simple didnt even need the exact